# How to kill/unregister/remove a Selenium node from a Grid

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, selenium-rc, selenium-grid

I manage a Selenium Grid. And I want to remove or unregister a node from Grid with a command line or something like that because I don't have access to the PC registered as a selenium Node, but I can see its IP from the Grid.

This is the script to register that node:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role node -hub http://10.0.50.34:4444/grid/register/
```

I can't find anyway to stop this script. I tried to shutdown the Hub and restarted it, but this node was registered again, because the script was still running and waiting for the hub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try blocking the IP, if it is blocked it wont receive anything from the node machine and it wont be displayed.

Comment: Not a bad idea, but the other answer is the best solution for me.

Answer (score 6):

You can unregister a node with an http command:

```
http://node_ip_address:port/selenium-server/driver/?cmd=shutDownSeleniumServer
```

EDIT: since Selenium 3 you must load this servlet (org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet) at startup and, depending if you created a hub or a node, use this calls for shutdown:

Hub

```
http://host:port/grid/admin/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown
```

Node

```
http://host:port/extra/LifecycleServlet?action=shutdown
```

Hope this helps

Comment: tried this but got a selenium help page link instead: `Whoops! The URL specified routes to this help page.` and the node is still online

Comment: You need to specify `-servlet org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet` when starting the node/hub for these to work. Or `SE_OPTS="-servlet org.openqa.grid.web.servlet.LifecycleServlet"` when using docker-selenium. See also: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2852#issuecomment-250841027